# MongoDB Docker and Robo 3T

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I am running mongo docker image from dockerhub in docker desktop on windows and connect to it with Robo 3T

In Robo 3T I am trying to create a new database "users" it seems to succeed but when I am closing Robo 3T
and opening it again I do not see the database I've created. What can it be wrong ?
The log records in mongo:

{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.503+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.507+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.508+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.509+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"65b9eb39f125"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.509+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.2","gitVersion":"15e73dc5738d2278b688f8929aee605fe4279b0e","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.509+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.509+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.512+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/data/db/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.513+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.514+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.514+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See [http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}](http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem%22,%22tags%22:%5B%22startupWarnings%22%5D%7D)
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:51.514+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=5809M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.294+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:294724][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.385+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:385096][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.517+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:517662][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 2/37120 to 3/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.518+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:518909][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.592+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:592271][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:636818][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1613757172:636944][1:0x7fdada605ac0], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.756+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":1242}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.756+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.759+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.761+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.781+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22178,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'. We suggest setting it to 'never'","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.787+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.791+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.798+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.799+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:52.799+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:52:53.076+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20631,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost","attr":{"error":{"code":0,"codeName":"OK"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.713+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.1:57648","connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.716+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.1:57648","client":"conn1","doc":{"application":{"name":"robo3t-1.4.2"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.2.6-17-g6bce88c"},"os":{"type":"Windows","name":"Microsoft Windows 8","architecture":"x86_64","version":"6.2 (build 9200)"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.739+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"172.17.0.1:57648"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.797+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.1:57652","connectionId":2,"connectionCount":2}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":51800,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"client metadata","attr":{"remote":"172.17.0.1:57652","client":"conn2","doc":{"application":{"name":"MongoDB Shell"},"driver":{"name":"MongoDB Internal Client","version":"4.2.6-17-g6bce88c"},"os":{"type":"Windows","name":"Microsoft Windows 8","architecture":"x86_64","version":"6.2 (build 9200)"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:11.847+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20250,   "ctx":"conn2","msg":"Successful authentication","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"172.17.0.1:57652"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:20.836+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20320,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"createCollection","attr":{"namespace":"users.temp","uuidDisposition":"generated","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"118968ba-6555-4e6e-a0c7-45b0ff596516"}},"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:20.913+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":20345,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Index build: done building","attr":{"buildUUID":null,"namespace":"users.temp","index":"*id*","commitTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:20.916+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":518070,  "ctx":"conn1","msg":"CMD: drop","attr":{"namespace":"users.temp"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:20.916+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":23879,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"About to abort all index builders","attr":{"namespace":"users.temp","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"118968ba-6555-4e6e-a0c7-45b0ff596516"}},"reason":"Collection users.temp(118968ba-6555-4e6e-a0c7-45b0ff596516) is being dropped"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-02-19T17:53:20.916+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20318,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Finishing collection drop","attr":{"namespace":"users.temp","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"118968ba-6555-4e6e-a0c7-45b0ff596516"}}}}

Answer (score 0):

Just try to insert something inside users collection. After that restart Robo3T.
Even inside mongo cli you create with `use users` command without inserting something you are not able to see among collections.